# Cannot access public static variable member

Tags: c++, c++11

I've declared a public static member to keep the total count of the instances of my class. The code is as follows:

```
class Hello {
public:
    static int myCount;
    void test(){
        //do nothing
    };
    Hello(){
        Hello::myCount += 1;
    };
    ~Hello() {
        Hello::myCount -= 1;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    Hello *p1 = new Hello();p1->test();
    Hello *p2 = new Hello();p2->test();
    cout << Hello::myCount;

    return 0;
}
```

However, I when compile, it says:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Hello::myCount", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
      Hello::Hello() in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I don't know where I'm wrong. It's been years from the last time I worked with c++, so could you please suggest a solution?
Thank you.

Comment: Define it outside of the class definition. `int Hello::myCount;`

Answer (score 4):

**Static members have to be defined outside of the class**, e.g.:

```
class Hello {
public:
    static int myCount;
    void test(){
        //do nothing
    };
    Hello(){
        Hello::myCount += 1;
    };
    ~Hello() {
        Hello::myCount -= 1;
    }
};

int Hello::myCount = 0; // definition outside of the class

(...)
```

Here is an example to show, that it helps to solve your problem: http://ideone.com/LVXVCc

It's all because a rule called **One Definition Rule**.
You can read more about this one in a context of static class members [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule#Definitions_of_static_const_data_members).

In short: `static int myCount` declaration is not a definition of a member. Classes are usually placed in their `.h/.hpp` header files and are included to many other files. If those'd contain static member and lines like the one above would be a definition, it will lead to the multiple-definitions error.

To prevent that, this declaration is not treated as a definition and you must define it yourself later.

Comment: Also, since the intention is probably to count the instances of the class, it would be a good idea to initialize the value.

Comment: @Aziuth, I haven't paid attention, but yes, of course.

Comment: If in another file, I define `int Hello::myCount = 999; `, then what happens